# disabling and enabling bootstrap switch using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

I am using bootstrap switch and currently got stuck as there aren't any strong documentation or examples that I could get access to.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="pull-left">
     <input class="switch" type="checkbox" id="cb_project_status"  name="cb_project_status" 
        <?php if($data_p_projectstatus=="ACTIVE") echo("checked"); else echo("");?> 
        data-on-color="success" data-off-text="Inactive" data-on-text="Active" 
        data-off-color="warning" data-size="mini" disabled>
     </div> 
 </div>
```

On document ready of js file, I do

```
$("#cb_project_status").bootstrapSwitch();
```

and have attached in in the php page

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css">
```

I need to achieve the following functionality: Unless user enters all mandatory fields, the switch button needs to be disabled.

```
if($.fn.validateFormInputs()){
   // enable bootstrap switch
}else{
   // disable bootstrap switch
}
```

What is the jQuery command to enable/disable bootstrap switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do it in many ways as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qu8yzsdk/)**

> **Using options**

**Type 1**

*With initialization*

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({
    disabled:true
});
```

**Type 2**

*After initialization*

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(); //initialized somewhere
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',true);
```

> **Using Method**

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(); //initialized somewhere
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('toggleDisabled',true,true);
```

**[Documentation](http://bootstrapswitch.com/documentation-2.html)**

Comment: After using : $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch('disabled',true);

https://photos.app.goo.gl/z1itgtTMynMfVdYu2

Comment: If you have a custom bootstrap-switch (with images and such) it reverts to the default switch which is not preferred. I fixed this by disabling it on initialization and then re-enable it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you `enable` and `disable` a lot you can also write your own methods:

```
$.fn.disable_switch = function() {
  this.bootstrapSwitch('toggleDisabled',true,true);
};

$.fn.enable_switch = function() {
  this.bootstrapSwitch('toggleDisabled',true,true);
};
```

Usage:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").disable_switch()
```